# Repeating and propaganation Function. Jquery

Tags: jquery, events, mouseover, mouseleave

Hey there i dont know if the title is the correct way to say what my problem is but i will try to explain it here.

So my bug is everthyng works for the first few times but after hovering and leaving the div more often it wont work anymore it starts lagging the animation starts 10 secs later and more.
i tried fixing it with `event.stopPropagation()` but that did not work.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G3pVz/5/)

Here the html

[...]

```
 <div class="box" id="box_1">
        <div class="content_box hidden" id="cont_1">
            <div class="con" id="con_1">Test1</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

[...]

And The Jquery Code

```
$( ".box" ).mouseover(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var attr = $( this ).attr("id");
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 1;i<=9;i++){
        if(attr=="box_"+i){
             $('#con_'+i).removeClass('hidden');
             $('#cont_'+i).removeClass('hidden');
             $(this).stop().animate({width: "300px"}, 100);
             $('#cont_'+i).stop().delay(100).animate({width: "250px"},1).animate({height: "400px"},500);
        }
    }
             $(this).delay(100).mouseleave(function(e) { 
              e.stopPropagation();   
              for(var i = 1;i<=9;i++){
               if(attr=="box_"+i){
                $('.con').addClass('hidden');
                $('#cont_'+i).stop().animate({height: "0px"},500).animate({wdith: "0px"});
                $(this).stop().delay(500).animate({
                    width: "50px"
                });      
               }
             }                 
             });         

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [delay api](https://api.jquery.com/delay)

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.